# Batch file to delete sub folder(s) from parent with exception(s)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my Batch File Code:

```
@ECHO ON
cd D:\Parent_Folder
del /s /q D:\Parent_Folder\
rmdir /s /q D:\Parent_Folder\
```

Parent_Folder:

- Abc (Folder)
- xyz.zip

I want to delete only Abc folder from my Parent Folder but i want to keep xyz.zip file with this code its getting deleted all the data from parent folder.

Comment: You need to specify if you want to delete/remove the content of `Parent_Folder` except for `xyz.zip`, whether you want to delete/remove all sub directories from `Parent_Folder` leaving all files in place, if you wish to remove only the `Abc` directory or something different.

Comment: yes i want to delete all the content of parent_folder except for xyz.zip

Comment: is it specifically the xyz.zip or all the files inside the sub-folders. And where do you want to store the files thereafter then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do this in PowerShell, you could use the following. When you are satisfied that the correct files and directories would be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from `Remove-Item`. Of course, change the directory path and filename to keep to yours.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:/src/t/' -Exclude 't.py' |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

If you are desperate to do this from cmd.exe, you could do something like this.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\src\t' -Exclude 't.py' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf"
```

Comment: A `|Where-Object Name -ne 't.py'|` to exclude an item would be more efficient than a foreach and an if.

Comment: @LotPings - I tried using `-Exclude`, but was not successful. That is when I was also trying to use `-File` and it returned nothing. I will edit the answer.